# Database cursor + while loop within

Tags: sql-server

This function I have created to return all recorded Stock numbers in the Table "ContributorDeeds" the table contains only the start number of the stocks and the end number of the stocks (e.g, from number - to number) I need to get all the numbers between within that range.

The function works fine, however, it tasks several minutes to return the result :(.

Is there a better SQL Query to get the same result?

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[StockNumbers] ()
RETURNS @SequenceNumbersOfShares TABLE (StockNumber NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DeedDocumentID BIGINT
DECLARE @MIN NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @MAX NVARCHAR(50)

--CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable(StockNumber NVARCHAR(50)) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ContributorDeedsID FROM dbo.ContributorDeeds WHERE DeedFromShare IS NOT NULL AND DeedToShare IS NOT NULL

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DeedDocumentID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @MIN = (SELECT DeedFromShare FROM ContributorDeeds WHERE ContributorDeedsID = @DeedDocumentID)
SET @MAX = (SELECT DeedToShare FROM ContributorDeeds WHERE ContributorDeedsID =  @DeedDocumentID)
WHILE dbo.InsertSP(@MIN, 20) <= dbo.InsertSP(@MAX, 20)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @SequenceNumbersOfShares(StockNumber) VALUES(@MIN)
SET    @MIN = @MIN + 1
END
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DeedDocumentID
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Do you know what "formatting" is? Try applying some to the text block you post here.

Comment: And yes, there is. What about you join with a numbers table?

Comment: I would imagine it is slow. You have a while loop nested inside of a cursor. And why in the world do you declare MIN and MAX as nvarchar??? You are using them as integers. Last time I checked there are no unicode characters required in any representation of an integer. This entire nested looping construct can be rewritten as a single insert statement if you use a numbers or tally table.

Comment: "Tom Tom" sorry about formatting but I was posting the answer on hurry because it was the end of the working time.

Comment: What do you mean by "join with a numbers table"!!! I declare the MIN and MAX NVARCHAR because the data type of the columns DeedFromShare and DeedToShare also NVARCHAR. You are saying that the nested loop can be rewritten using a single statement how? What is tally table?